# Java Generics wildcard query

Tags: java, generics

I have 2 queries related to Java Generics

**1)** I am very new to java generics. I am trying to cast wildcard as below:

```
void meth(List<?> list) {
   List<Integer> integers = (List<Integer>)list; //how to find the type of object from wildcard?
}
```

I wanna find out the type of object from List<?> ,then verify with instanceOf and then assign it to appropriate list (for eg: List< Integer >). May I know how to find the type of object from wildcard list?

**2)** I have a method as below:

```
public static <T extends Number> void copy(List<T> dest, List<T> src) {

    }
```

then why am I getting compile error while trying to call as copy(integers, floats); , whats wrong here?

Comment: I don't get a compile error from your first snippet.  There's an unchecked cast warning, but that's not an error.  What's your error?

Comment: What the OP is doing though is inherently unsafe.  Guaranteed to cause a runtime error 99.99% of the time.  Or more often.

Comment: Yes, but whenever you cast, you're kind of taking responsibility for the fact that the types are OK.  Casting any expression is like crossing the road.  If you're a responsible adult, you look both ways first.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem am sorry, iam too not getting any compile error, i just edited my query, may I know how to find type of object from wildcard?

Comment: @markspace  i just edited my query, may I know how to find type of object from wildcard?

Comment: You can't find the type of the object from the wildcard.  What you should do is use a type parameter, like in your second snippet, and constrain the type parameter to what you need it to be.

Answer (score 0):

For #1 I see some design issues but if you do want to know the class I think you can use something like this

```
if(list.get(0) instanceof Integer) {
  System.out.println("This is an integer");
}
```

For #2 both dest and src have the same generic class T, if you them to be different you will have to introduce a new generic. Please try this

```
public static <T extends Number, R extends Number> void copy(List<T> dest, List<R> src) { 
// your code
}
```